# while running SimpleAuth.php it gives fatal error in restler

Tags: php, restler

I am running this following url and trying to run SimpleAuth.php

`http://localhost/restler/public/examples/nof/SimpleAuth.php`
    and it gives

```
Fatal error: Interface 'Luracast\Restler\iAuthenticate' not found in C:\wamp\www\Restler\public\examples\nof\SimpleAuth.php on line 5
```

content of SimpleAuth.php

```
use Luracast\Restler\iAuthenticate;

class SimpleAuth implements iAuthenticate
{
    const KEY = 'rEsTlEr2';

    function __isAllowed()
    {
        return isset($_GET['key']) && $_GET['key'] == SimpleAuth::KEY ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }

    function key()
    {
        return SimpleAuth::KEY;
    }
}
```

iAuthenticate.php

```
namespace Luracast\Restler;

interface iAuthenticate extends iFilter{  }
```

Comment: kindly enable error display on in .htaccess file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you are directly calling `C:\wamp\www\Restler\public\examples\nof\SimpleAuth.php' which you should not be doing, and it wont work unless you include restler.php

make sure your index.php includes restler.php correctly, once it does so, our autoloader should be able to load the 'Luracast\Restler\iAuthenticate' just fine.

You should not attempt creating restler api class yourself.

Comment: ok and one more thing how can i pass value with query string and with out for example /add/4/4  and add?n1=4&n2=4

Answer (score 0):

have you define namespace properly
is iAuthenticate is valid and defined

is you are auto loading
namespace Luracast\Restler\iAuthenticate or not ?

Comment: yeah it define correctly. but i am not sure about autoloading bcoz its done in framework.I have added iAuthenticate.php .pls varify and help me out

Answer (score 0):

in my test its working perfectly

look at this

```
namespace Luracast\Restler;

interface iAuthenticate {

}

use Luracast\Restler\iAuthenticate as ia;

class SimpleAuth implements ia {

    const KEY = 'rEsTlEr2';

    function __isAllowed() {
        return isset($_GET['key']) && $_GET['key'] == SimpleAuth::KEY ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }

    function key() {
        return SimpleAuth::KEY;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you tell me mistake i m doing ?

Comment: already mention aboven or replace interface iAuthenticate extends iFilter{  } with interface iAuthenticate extends \iFilter{  } if iFilter is global

Comment: nope its not global ,its just another interface with one method function __isAllowed() {}